# Most Boehm clarinets have 17 keys, but some have 18 or 19. What are the extra keys used for?

Tags: clarinet

Clarinet beginner here. Most Boehm clarinets have 17 keys, but you can get [18 keys](https://www.thomann.de/gb/buffet_crampon_prodige_bb_clarinet_18_5.htm) for not much more money, and there are a few very expensive clarinets with [19 keys](https://www.thomann.de/gb/buffet_tosca_bbklarinette_186.htm).

What do the extra keys do, and are they useful at a beginner to intermediate level?

Key 18 is apparently a left hand Eb lever, but which Eb? Do you get an extra semitone below the lowest E on a normal clarinet?
Key 19 I have no idea except that it's an extra key for the right hand pinky.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find fingering charts online for R-13, R-14, etc. models .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 18th key is usually a left hand Eb/Ab lever. This is an alternative to the right hand Eb/Ab lever and makes fingering combinations involving both fourth fingers much easier. It's become standard on higher quality instruments.

The 19th key is normally found only on so-called 'full-boehm' clarinets that have some other extra keywork as well. This gives you an extra note, the low Eb, which is sometimes useful for transposing A-clarinet parts. For most players the advantages don't outweigh the extra cost, weight and complication.
In the case of the 'Tosca' clarinet you've linked to, the extra key has a different function: it opens a hole to improve the pitch of the lowest F which is often flat.

Comment: Eb/Ab or Eb/Bb?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Eb/(low)Ab. The Bb/Eb key for LH3 is standard on all instruments.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a description](http://test.woodwind.org/clarinet/BBoard/read.html?f=1&i=330071&t=329854) from someone who appears to know his clarinet variants:

> Chris: Yes, R14 is forked Eb/Bb, R15 is articulated G#, and R16 is
> both. There are additional designations for extra keys - a modern R13
> Prestige would be R13 1/2 since it has a 5th LH key for alternative
> G#/Eb. Full Boehm with low Eb was R16 3/4. So maybe R1 was a tube with
> holes and no keywork at all

Another responder in that thread posted a nice [link](http://test.woodwind.org/clarinet/BBoard/download.html/1,2226/Buffet%20catalog.jpg) to an old Buffet Catalog page, shown here:
[image]

I recall fondly :-) how hugely expensive those prices seemed back then.